# Set up HTACCESS to exclude rewriting urls of a certain folder

Tags: .htaccess

Hi guys I have an htaccess file setup as below which translates url parameters into easy to ready urls i.e index.php?customer=2 becomes index/customer/2

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fltdata.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.fltdata.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htm|html)$ index.php 

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

AddType text/css .css
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

I want to set it up so it excludes a certain test folder so that if I type in lets say mysite.com/test it opens a test folder and not treat it like a parameter. Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Adding: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` should make "real" folders have priority over your rewrites.